# Opencv videostream of two cameras in the same window

Tags: python, opencv, video, stream, capture

I am trying to stream two cameras simultaneously into one window using opencv. Any idea how can I do it?
I can do it using different windows and threading but I wanted to incorporate the two streams into one window.

NOTE: The cameras have the same resolution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this should work with the below example. please try this.

```
#for image
ret1, img1 = camera1.read()
ret2, img2 = camera2.read()
if ret1==False or ret2==False:
      print("could not read from cameras !")
      return

# now, you can do this either vertical (one over the other):
final = cv2.vconcat([img1, img2])

# or horizontal (next to each other):
#final = cv2.hconcat([img1, img2])

imshow("I", final)
waitKey(10)
```

For further reference please see this https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d2/de8/group__core__array.html#ga4676b1376cdc4e528dab6bd9edc51c1a

```
#for video: P.S: It should be like this, but I didn't test it with video.

cap_1= cv2.VideoCapture(CAP_ANY)
cap_2 = cv2.VideoCapture(CAP_ANY)
  
while true:
      ret_1, frame_1 = cap_1.read()
      ret_2, frame_2 = cap_2.read()

# now, you can do this either vertical (one over the other):
     final = cv2.vconcat([frame_1, frame_2])

# or horizontal (next to each other):
#final = cv2.hconcat([img1, img2])

       imshow("I", final)
       waitKey(10)
```

Comment: But this is not a stream this is just one capture. I want to have a video (using cv2.VideoCapture perhaps).

Comment: Just try to add by frames in while loop. Answer is updated and check it out now.

Comment: cameras will drift apart over time. this will not work for long.